# Explanation of the tables found in Kyber round1 code?

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, lattice-crypto, constants, kyber

The `precomp.c` file in Kyber NIST round 1 submission has three tables, could you please let me know how to generate these three tables? If I want to understand how these tables work, which paper should I read?

The code with the constants in the tables follows below:

```
/* Precomputed constants for the forward NTT and inverse NTT.
 * Computed using Pari/GP as follows:
 *
brv=[0,128,64,192,32,160,96,224,16,144,80,208,48,176,112,240, \
     8,136,72,200,40,168,104,232,24,152,88,216,56,184,120,248, \
     4,132,68,196,36,164,100,228,20,148,84,212,52,180,116,244, \
     12,140,76,204,44,172,108,236,28,156,92,220,60,188,124,252, \
     2,130,66,194,34,162,98,226,18,146,82,210,50,178,114,242, \
     10,138,74,202,42,170,106,234,26,154,90,218,58,186,122,250, \
     6,134,70,198,38,166,102,230,22,150,86,214,54,182,118,246, \
     14,142,78,206,46,174,110,238,30,158,94,222,62,190,126,254, \
     1,129,65,193,33,161,97,225,17,145,81,209,49,177,113,241, \
     9,137,73,201,41,169,105,233,25,153,89,217,57,185,121,249, \
     5,133,69,197,37,165,101,229,21,149,85,213,53,181,117,245, \
     13,141,77,205,45,173,109,237,29,157,93,221,61,189,125,253, \
     3,131,67,195,35,163,99,227,19,147,83,211,51,179,115,243, \
     11,139,75,203,43,171,107,235,27,155,91,219,59,187,123,251, \
     7,135,71,199,39,167,103,231,23,151,87,215,55,183,119,247, \
     15,143,79,207,47,175,111,239,31,159,95,223,63,191,127,255];

q = 7681;
n = 256;
mont = Mod(2^18,q);

g=0; for(i=2,q-1,if(znorder(Mod(i,q)) == 2*n, g=Mod(i,q); break))

zetas = lift(vector(n, i, g^(brv[i])*mont))
omegas_inv_bitrev_montgomery = lift(vector(n/2, i, (g^2)^(-brv[2*(i-1)+1])*mont))
psis_inv_montgomery = lift(vector(n, i, g^(-(i-1))/n*mont))

*/

const uint16_t zetas[KYBER_N] = {
  990, 7427, 2634, 6819, 578, 3281, 2143, 1095, 484, 6362, 3336, 5382, 6086, 3823, 877, 5656,
  3583, 7010, 6414, 263, 1285, 291, 7143, 7338, 1581, 5134, 5184, 5932, 4042, 5775, 2468, 3,
  606, 729, 5383, 962, 3240, 7548, 5129, 7653, 5929, 4965, 2461, 641, 1584, 2666, 1142, 157,
  7407, 5222, 5602, 5142, 6140, 5485, 4931, 1559, 2085, 5284, 2056, 3538, 7269, 3535, 7190, 1957,
  3465, 6792, 1538, 4664, 2023, 7643, 3660, 7673, 1694, 6905, 3995, 3475, 5939, 1859, 6910, 4434,
  1019, 1492, 7087, 4761, 657, 4859, 5798, 2640, 1693, 2607, 2782, 5400, 6466, 1010, 957, 3851,
  2121, 6392, 7319, 3367, 3659, 3375, 6430, 7583, 1549, 5856, 4773, 6084, 5544, 1650, 3997, 4390,
  6722, 2915, 4245, 2635, 6128, 7676, 5737, 1616, 3457, 3132, 7196, 4702, 6239, 851, 2122, 3009,
  7613, 7295, 2007, 323, 5112, 3716, 2289, 6442, 6965, 2713, 7126, 3401, 963, 6596, 607, 5027,
  7078, 4484, 5937, 944, 2860, 2680, 5049, 1777, 5850, 3387, 6487, 6777, 4812, 4724, 7077, 186,
  6848, 6793, 3463, 5877, 1174, 7116, 3077, 5945, 6591, 590, 6643, 1337, 6036, 3991, 1675, 2053,
  6055, 1162, 1679, 3883, 4311, 2106, 6163, 4486, 6374, 5006, 4576, 4288, 5180, 4102, 282, 6119,
  7443, 6330, 3184, 4971, 2530, 5325, 4171, 7185, 5175, 5655, 1898, 382, 7211, 43, 5965, 6073,
  1730, 332, 1577, 3304, 2329, 1699, 6150, 2379, 5113, 333, 3502, 4517, 1480, 1172, 5567, 651,
  925, 4573, 599, 1367, 4109, 1863, 6929, 1605, 3866, 2065, 4048, 839, 5764, 2447, 2022, 3345,
  1990, 4067, 2036, 2069, 3567, 7371, 2368, 339, 6947, 2159, 654, 7327, 2768, 6676, 987, 2214};

const uint16_t omegas_inv_bitrev_montgomery[KYBER_N/2] = {
  990, 254, 862, 5047, 6586, 5538, 4400, 7103, 2025, 6804, 3858, 1595, 2299, 4345, 1319, 7197,
  7678, 5213, 1906, 3639, 1749, 2497, 2547, 6100, 343, 538, 7390, 6396, 7418, 1267, 671, 4098,
  5724, 491, 4146, 412, 4143, 5625, 2397, 5596, 6122, 2750, 2196, 1541, 2539, 2079, 2459, 274,
  7524, 6539, 5015, 6097, 7040, 5220, 2716, 1752, 28, 2552, 133, 4441, 6719, 2298, 6952, 7075,
  4672, 5559, 6830, 1442, 2979, 485, 4549, 4224, 6065, 1944, 5, 1553, 5046, 3436, 4766, 959,
  3291, 3684, 6031, 2137, 1597, 2908, 1825, 6132, 98, 1251, 4306, 4022, 4314, 362, 1289, 5560,
  3830, 6724, 6671, 1215, 2281, 4899, 5074, 5988, 5041, 1883, 2822, 7024, 2920, 594, 6189, 6662,
  3247, 771, 5822, 1742, 4206, 3686, 776, 5987, 8, 4021, 38, 5658, 3017, 6143, 889, 4216};

const uint16_t psis_inv_montgomery[KYBER_N] = {
  1024, 4972, 5779, 6907, 4943, 4168,  315, 5580,   90,  497, 1123,  142, 4710, 5527, 2443, 4871, 
   698, 2489, 2394, 4003,  684, 2241, 2390, 7224, 5072, 2064, 4741, 1687, 6841,  482, 7441, 1235, 
  2126, 4742, 2802, 5744, 6287, 4933,  699, 3604, 1297, 2127, 5857, 1705, 3868, 3779, 4397, 2177, 
   159,  622, 2240, 1275,  640, 6948, 4572, 5277,  209, 2605, 1157, 7328, 5817, 3191, 1662, 2009, 
  4864,  574, 2487,  164, 6197, 4436, 7257, 3462, 4268, 4281, 3414, 4515, 3170, 1290, 2003, 5855, 
  7156, 6062, 7531, 1732, 3249, 4884, 7512, 3590, 1049, 2123, 1397, 6093, 3691, 6130, 6541, 3946, 
  6258, 3322, 1788, 4241, 4900, 2309, 1400, 1757,  400,  502, 6698, 2338, 3011,  668, 7444, 4580, 
  6516, 6795, 2959, 4136, 3040, 2279, 6355, 3943, 2913, 6613, 7416, 4084, 6508, 5556, 4054, 3782, 
    61, 6567, 2212,  779,  632, 5709, 5667, 4923, 4911, 6893, 4695, 4164, 3536, 2287, 7594, 2848, 
  3267, 1911, 3128,  546, 1991,  156, 4958, 5531, 6903,  483,  875,  138,  250, 2234, 2266, 7222, 
  2842, 4258,  812, 6703,  232, 5207, 6650, 2585, 1900, 6225, 4932, 7265, 4701, 3173, 4635, 6393, 
   227, 7313, 4454, 4284, 6759, 1224, 5223, 1447,  395, 2608, 4502, 4037,  189, 3348,   54, 6443, 
  2210, 6230, 2826, 1780, 3002, 5995, 1955, 6102, 6045, 3938, 5019, 4417, 1434, 1262, 1507, 5847, 
  5917, 7157, 7177, 6434, 7537,  741, 4348, 1309,  145,  374, 2236, 4496, 5028, 6771, 6923, 7421, 
  1978, 1023, 3857, 6876, 1102, 7451, 4704, 6518, 1344,  765,  384, 5705, 1207, 1630, 4734, 1563, 
  6839, 5933, 1954, 4987, 7142, 5814, 7527, 4953, 7637, 4707, 2182, 5734, 2818,  541, 4097, 5641};
```

Comment: Asking about the algorithm required to generate the tables is on topic here. Asking for code is not, so I have made some changes to the question to highlight what it is (or should be, for this site) about. Have you read the papers that were included in the submission to NIST? If so please indicate that fact in your question.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see in the comment of the code, the tables have been computed using Pari/GP, which mean you could regenerate them using the same code.

The details can be stitched together from [this Kyber paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/634.pdf) and from [the specification](https://pq-crystals.org/kyber/data/kyber-specification.pdf) of their first round proposal.

Notice that the function `brv()` is simply the bit reversal:
$$\mathrm{brv}(b_{log(n)−1}\cdot 2^{log(n)−1}+···+b_1\cdot 2 + b_0) =b_0\cdot2^{log(n)−1}  +\cdots + b_{\log(n)−2}\cdot 2 +b_{\log(n)−1}$$

and the table they included there is basically just a lookup table for the bit reversal:

brv(0) = 0, brv(1) = 0b10000000 = 128, brv(2) = 0b01000000 = 64, etc.

Then, since they work in a ring $R_q= \mathbb{Z}_{7681}/(X^{256}+1)$, they set $q=7681$ and $n=256$. (Notice this changed in their second round proposal! Now $q=3329$.)

Since NTT (number-theoretic transform) is an efficient way to do multiplications in $R_q$, they use it in their scheme, furthermore there are way to speed it up using lookups table, that's what they are building here.

Next in the code, they defined a so called "montgomery factor" $mont = 2^{18} \mod{q}$, I'll explain why at the end.

Then comes a somewhat strange loop:
`g=0; for(i=2,q-1,if(znorder(Mod(i,q)) == 2*n, g=Mod(i,q); break))`

What this loop is doing is basically checking whether the order in $\mathbb{Z^*}_q$ of $i\bmod{q}$ is equal to $2n = 2^9$ and if so, it sets $g = i \bmod{q}$ and stops the loop, this is basically an algorithm to the smallest element of order $2^9$ in   $\mathbb{Z}^*_q$, as per the paper page 10 (see "The NTT domain").

Next, they explain in the paper that $\mathrm{NTT}(a)$ for a polynomial $a = \sum^{255}_{i=0}a_iX^i \in R_q$ is defined as the polynomial $\sum^{255}_{i=0}\left( \sum^{255}_{j=0} \psi^ja_j(\omega)^{ij} \right)X^i$.

But notice that they mention that $\psi=\sqrt{\omega}=g$ (our $g$ from the above loop). Also notice that the NTT sums are raising $\psi$ and $\omega$ to the same power every time.

So, what they are doing is: they precompute the said power of $\psi$ and $\omega$ and that is what these tables are. Lookup table for these values. 
The $\zeta$ table is a lookup table for the power of $\psi=g$, whereas the two other are for the inverse of these power ($\psi^{-i}$ for $0 \leq i\leq 255$ and $\omega^{-j}$ for $0 \leq j \leq 127$), this is probably because they want to use them in the inverse NTT function instead of the NTT function.
But, it is important to notice, as mentioned in the spec, that **the coefficient of the polynomial are stored in bitreversed order**, which means they need to fiddle a bit with the index of their elements.
That is, coefficient $a_i$ will be stored at index $\mathrm{brv}(i)$, not at index $i$, so they need to account for that in their lookup tables.

Now, why divide by $n$ in the `psis_inv_montgomery`? Well, this is simply because there the coefficients of the inverse NTT polynomial have a constant factor $n^{-1}$.

Now, regarding why they multiply their constant value  by a factor $mont$, the answer can be found in Section 3.1 of [these paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/039.pdf). The goal here is simply to ensure that the result will be congruent to the correct value in the end when using Montgomery reduction, and the answer to "but why?" is "for performance purposes".