# How are the constants found in the AVX2 implementation of CRYSTALS-KYBER round 2 generated?

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, implementation, lattice-crypto, constants, kyber

The post-quantum lattice-based cryptosystem CRYSTALS-KYBER which has made it to the second round of NIST PQC includes two implementations: 1) a baseline reference implementation in C and 2) an optimized AVX2 implementation. The code repository can be found [here](https://github.com/pq-crystals/kyber).

The AVX2 implementation includes some precomputed constants in `consts.c` such as `_ZETAS_EXP` and `_ZETAS_INV_EXP`. I understand that these precomputed constants are used in Number Theoretic Transform (NTT) and its inverse. I also understand how their counterparts - found in the reference implementation -
have been generated thanks to this [question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/74248/explanation-of-the-tables-found-in-kyber-round1-code). However, I am not able to understand how they have been generated in the AVX2 implementation? And why some of them are not even reduced modulo `q` in `[0, q-1]`?

I read the following papers (listed below) in order to understand that, but I could not find detailed information related to my questions. The only information that might be relevant can be found in Section 4 in [3](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/039.pdf), which I include below for convenience:

> **Precomputed roots**. Instead of loading single precomputed roots and
> populating the vector registers with broadcast and various shuffling
> instructions, which is slow, we precompute vectors of roots that can
> be loaded into a vector register with one aligned load instruction
> vmovdqa only.

The following papers describe the initial development of Kyber and how it has evolved:

1. Initial implementation - round 1 submission is described [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/634.pdf) and [here](https://pq-crystals.org/kyber/data/kyber-specification.pdf).
2. A faster AVX2 implementation is described [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/039.pdf).
3. A more optimized version (with smaller modulus reduced from `q = 7681` to `q = 3329`) uses some ideas from this [paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/040.pdf).

I appreciate if someone could explain or refer to other sources which can help understand how these constants are generated.

Comment: There are parts of the second paper which are likely more relevant --- in particular see the "Constant-time modular reduction" subsection, which answers why some constants are not reduced mod $q$. It seems to be that the precomputed constants are powers of the root of unity, but in a representation that is more friendly for later modular reductions.